# Interpret Some Functions in C

Tags: c, function, unix, adventure

I was wondering if anyone can explain to me what is happening in the following chunks of code.  The code is being used to creates random connections between 7 rooms, ensuring that each room has a minimum of 3 connections.

```
void bitcodeToEdge(int bitcode, int *edge)
{
    int i = 0; 
    int j = 0; 
    while (i < 2 && bitcode > 0) {
        if (bitcode % 2 == 1) {
            edge[i] = j;
            i++;
        }
        bitcode >>= 1;
        j++;
    }
    for (; i < 2; ++i) edge[i] = -1;
}

void edgeToBitcode(int *edge, int *bitcode)
{
    *bitcode = power(2, edge[0]) + power(2, edge[1]);
}

void connectRooms(int *rooms, char *dir, char **filenames, char **roomNames)
{
    int i, j;
    FILE *file;
    char filename[100]; 
    int bitcode; 
    int edge[2]; 
    int *edges; 
    int edgeIdx;
    int maxEdges;
    int minEdges; 
    int randEdges; 
    int valencies[10]; 
    maxEdges = 21;
    edgeIdx = 0;
    edges = malloc(sizeof(int) * maxEdges);
    assert(edges != NULL);
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < 10; ++j) {
            edge[0] = rooms[i];
            edge[1] = rooms[j];
            edgeToBitcode(edge, &bitcode);
            edges[edgeIdx] = bitcode;
            edgeIdx++;
        }
    }
    permute(edges, maxEdges);
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) valencies[i] = INT_MAX;
    for (i = 0; i < 7; ++i) valencies[rooms[i]] = 0;
    edgeIdx = 0;
    minEdges = 10;
    randEdges =  getRandInt(minEdges, maxEdges);
    while (edgeIdx < randEdges || getIntArrayMin(valencies, 7) < 3)
    {
        bitcodeToEdge(edges[edgeIdx], edge);
        valencies[edge[0]] += 1;
        valencies[edge[1]] += 1;
        for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
            strcpy(filename, dir);
            strcat(filename, filenames[edge[i]]);
            if ((file = fopen(filename, "a")) == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "could not open %s for writing\n", filename);
                exit(2);
            }
            fprintf(file, "\nCONNECTION %d: %s",
            valencies[edge[i]],
            roomNames[edge[1 - i]]);
            fclose(file);
        }
        edgeIdx++;
    }
    free(edges);
}
```

Power works just like pow - x^y
`GetIntArrayMin` gets the minimum integer value  in the array
Permute creates a pseudo-random permutation of a specified integer array.

I don't understand what bitcode is at all.  Maybe if someone could just explain that at first I could get an understanding of the rest.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's just a binary string of booleans. It's processed a bit at a time in the first function. The combination

```
if( bitcode % 2 == 1)
```

...

```
bitcode >>= 1
```

Achieves this.

Answer (score 0):

Bitcode is an int and a convenient storage for random data. In the first function it is just an array of booleans.  The int is processed by the following code

```
if( bitcode % 2 == 1) 
...
Bitcode >>=1
```

It would have been clearer if & (not to be confused with &&) had been used.

```
if(bitcode & 1)
```

Comment: Is there a simpler way of doing this? I.E without bitcode?

Comment: Although you don't understand it, it's a cool way to create a load of random booleans. To do the same requires an array of booleans, bool bytecode [32]; where rand or what ever populates bit code you would require a for loop calling rand and setting to true or false. Similar for loops would be required to access it.

Comment: Well I have to do this myself, so I'm trying to understand it further and possibly in another way so I can actually code it myself

Answer (score 0):

Bitcode is short representation of edge. It always contains two bits set to 1. When these two bits are set on positions N,M it means that connection between N,M exists.

Also some statements about bit coded edges:

- (bitcode1 & bitcode2) != 0 means that corresponding edges are belong one room
- bitcode is not directed that means that no one-way connections are possible (if N is connected to M then M is connected to N)